# Generic style for entire application

Tags: android, xml, styles, manifest

I've been failing miserably to get my app looking 'nice'. A previous post on the subject linked to a very good site explaining how to create a single style file, effectively over-writing the default theme elements with my own eg. set the basic 'button' to have a green background without having to use a 'style' or 'background' attribute for each individual button.

I have tried to implement this but it does not seem to be working - this is what I have in my manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/spyEyeTheme" >
```

This is the single file:

```
<style name="spyEyeTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">

    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/myButton</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/myTextView</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/myEditText</item>

</style>

<style name="myTextView" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>

</style>

<style name="myEditText" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <!-- item name="android:textSize">30sp</item> -->
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/lime</item>
</style>

<style name="myButton" parent="android:Theme.Light">

    <item name="android:background">#008000</item>  <--- green background for button

</style>
```

In theory, if I now define a button in an XML file, it should produce a button with a green background:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/loadBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/newBtn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:onClick="loadGame"
    android:text="@string/load"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:typeface="sans" />
```

Unfortunately, it is not. No error but the button is being displayed with the standard grey background (and other attributes don't work either). It's as if the system can't find or is ignoring my style redirects.

Any ideas?

EDIT: OK, got it working but not sure why. In Eclipse, while on the 'Graphical Layout' tab for my XML file, I noticed a drop down list at the top of the screen, which was showing 'AppTheme'. The drop down had an option to change to my 'spyEyeTheme', which I did and now it is working.

However, I cannot see any changes to my code - can anyone explain what has happened?

Comment: Are you apply this theme to application or activity in you AndroidManifest file? If for application make sure you don't override with some other style in activity declaration

Comment: In the application and I don't set it anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I think your button style should inherite from Widget.Button

```
<style name="myButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">#008000</item>  <--- green background for button
</style>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work either (I also tried it with '@android' after seeing another post but no good).